# Pagination Elasticsearch in Django

Tags: django, elasticsearch

I am a newbie in Elasticsearch, I just try to create a search engine using it in Django. Overall, the engine shows good results. Unfortunately, it loads a large number of the results. Then, I try to paginate it by regular pagination in Django, after that, the page load error `object of type 'Search' has no len()`.

These are my codes:

view.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
from elasticsearch_dsl import Search
from django.core.paginator import Paginator

def search_es(request):
    return render(request,'search/search.html')

def results(request):
    s = Search(using=Elasticsearch())
    keyword = request.GET.get('q') # keyword that want to be found
    print(keyword)
    if keyword:
        # posts = s.query('match_phrase_prefix',head_title=keyword)
        # if posts.count() == 0:
        posts = s.query(
            "multi_match",
            query=keyword,
            fields=['head_title^5', 'description^5', 'description.ngram'],
            # type="phrase_prefix",
        )
        posts = posts[0: 100]
    else:
        posts = ''

    page = request.GET.get('page', 1)
    paginator = Paginator(posts, 10)
    try:
        users = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        users = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        users = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    context = {
        'page_title': keyword,
        'posts': users,
        'count': posts.count(),
        'keyword': keyword,
    }

    return render(request,'search/results.html',context)
```

results.html

```
{% if posts.has_other_pages %}
  <ul class="pagination">
    {% if posts.has_previous %}
      <li><a href="?page={{ posts.previous_page_number }}">«</a></li>
    {% else %}
      <li class="disabled"><span>«</span></li>
    {% endif %}
    {% for i in posts.paginator.page_range %}
      {% if posts.number == i %}
        <li class="active"><span>{{ i }} <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></span></li>
      {% else %}
        <li><a href="?page={{ i }}">{{ i }}</a></li>
      {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    {% if posts.has_next %}
      <li><a href="?page={{ posts.next_page_number }}">»</a></li>
    {% else %}
      <li class="disabled"><span>»</span></li>
    {% endif %}
  </ul>
{% endif %}
```

Hope for every possible solution.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

ElasticSearch provided two parameters you can use for pagination: `from` and `size`. You can refer to https://elasticsearch-dsl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/search_dsl.html#pagination

for example:

```
        posts = s[0:20].query(
            "multi_match",
            query=keyword,
            fields=['head_title^5', 'description^5', 'description.ngram'],
            # type="phrase_prefix",
        )
```

to get first page, and page size is 20.

Comment: Unfortunately, it just returns the 20 results in the page not paginate for all results.